# What is the meaning of Sanatan?

Tags: etymology

The real name of Hinduism is Sanatan Dharma.

I want to know what is the meaning of the word - Sanatan ?

Some people say Sanatan means -Eternal
Some people say Sanatan means - Old.

What is the real meaning of Sanatan Dharma ?